# Oracle Backup Strategy

Tags: database, oracle, backup

I have recently inherited a smallish Oracle database running on a SPARC Solaris 10 Server. I have been asked to implement a sensible backup strategy. The database has about 3000 odd tables and is roughly about 19 GB in size (using the expdp utility). It has several hundred thousand transactions every day and the database is in Archivelog mode. At the moment on an interim basis i have a cron job running which exports the entire database out using expdp and then FTP it out to a different file server. On a weekly basis I have another cronjob running a RMAN command (backup database plus archivelog all delete input). I copy the backup files to a different partition on the same machine and once a month I move them to the file server to clear up some space.

I am a complete newbie to Oracle / Solaris and I am used to dealing with mySQL or MS SQL databases. Oracle seems to have more complex/exhaustive methods for backup and recovery strategies. I was wondering if someone could tell me if my above mentioned strategy is a good enough backup strategy and if it isn't could someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you in Advance

Alex

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a better answer to this on a forum dedicated to database or system administration, but the prima facie answer is: no, this is not a good backup solution for Oracle.

Datapump (`expdp`) is really only intended for moving data, not for use as a backup solution. You should be using `RMAN` for all of your backups and you're probably better off using `RMAN`'s internal scheduling rather than `cron` to manage the `RMAN` jobs.